# $_POST textarea content adding new lines automatically?

Tags: javascript, php

I am reading the contents of a text file with the help of PHP and filling the HTML page with these text file contents, and then when the html page is submitted, again the contents are posted into another text file, all the other parameters can be read without any problem but the text area seems to add new lines in between automatically.

The format of this input text file and generated output text file must match exactly.

PHP code to read from the input text file:

```
if(strpos($data[$ii],"BPI Info") !== false)
{
  for($jj=0;$jj<$datapoints;$jj++)
  {
    $databpi[$jj] = $data[$ii+$jj+1];
  }
 continue;
}
```

HTML code for the page:

```
<textarea id="data_srv" name="data_srv" rows="14" cols="35" ><?php for ($jj=0;$jj<$srvdatapoints;$jj++)echo($datasrv[$jj]."\n");?></textarea>
```

Here, the text area contents of input text file are as follows:

```
15.76 1
16.0397 0.9997
16.3194 0.9996
16.5992 0.9993
16.8789 0.999
17.1586 0.9988
```

PHP code to POST to an output text file:

```
file_put_contents($file, "\nBPI Info: \n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['data_bpi], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

But, when the POST is done, the generated output file contents are as follows:

```
15.76 1

16.0397 0.9997

16.3194 0.9996

16.5992 0.9993

16.8789 0.999

17.1586 0.9988
```

The new lines are added automatically, can anyone see where are these new lines coming from ?

Comment: On Windows systems new lines are represented by carriage returns (\r) and line feeds (\n).

Comment: `hexdump -C $file` What do your line endings look like? `0d0a` or just `0a`?